# Elasticsearch 2.x to 5.x query issue

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-2.0

The below query needs to be changed from version 2.x to version 5.x.

`filtered => bool`

But should is not supporting multiple queries.

```
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}
        },
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [{
                    "query": {
                        "match": {
                            "valid": "Y"
                        }
                    }
                }],
                "should": [
                    { "query": { "wildcard": { "name": { "value": '*' + searchValue + '*' } } } },
                    { "query": { "wildcard": { "fisrtname": { "value": '*' + searchValue + '*' } } } }   
                ]
            }
        }
    }
},
"sort": [{
    "name": {
        "order": "asec"
    }
}],
"from": 0,
"size": 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "valid": "Y"
              }
            }
          ],
          "should": [
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "name": {
                  "value": "searchValue"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "wildcard": {
                "firstname": {
                  "value": "searchValue"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "name": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "from": 0,
  "size": 15
}
```

The first bool.filter wrapper is so everything is treated as filter and not scored and possibly cached.

Comment: Thanks it worked.
But the only issue is with the sorting.

Comment: I corrected the answer, the field name for sort was incorrect.

Comment: No it still doesnt work.

**Sorting has changed in the new version and it doesnt work like v2.x.
In the new version it says we need to change the mapping on keyword.**


ref : [https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html]